# How to extract response data JSON and save variable to CSV file in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to extract key "count" from response data and write it's value (int) in CSV file.

I have used BeanShell PostProcessor for the same.

Below is script I have used:

```
count = vars.get("count");

f = new FileOutputStream("file path", true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(count);
f.close();
```

And JSON sample, I am trying to extract:

```
{"meta":{"message":"","is_error":false,"count":295,"next":"123","status":1000,"previous":""}
```

Doing this, "null" gets printed in CSV file.

Please let us know what am I missing here?

It supposed to be 295 gets printed in CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether your extractor is fetching the correct value. Below, I have used the same code and used regular expression extractor to fetch the values from the json. It is working fine.

Hope it helps.

[image]

**Update for Reg Ex**

Regular expression config;-
[image]

Below is to test the regular expression. You can always test your regular expression in view result tree using RegEx Tester:-

[image]

Comment: Thanks sunny. Have you used Regex extracor to extract count's value? I would appreciate it you can attach Regex extracor's snap.

Comment: @Palash Jain..Check if it helps. But, though I have given the answer, I personally go with Dmitri T answer.

Comment: Thanks sunny, it worked. I have one more doubt. Is there any way that I can write that "count" value while using non-gui mode in same test result csv file against it's thread?

Comment: Yes you can using jmeter variables..Check 4.6 section in the link https://gerardnico.com/jmeter/output_file. If it helped you can accept the answer,see stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

[Since JMeter 3.1 users are strongly advised to switch to JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) mainly because [Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).

So I would suggest going for [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) in order to extract the "count" value and write it into a file in a "single shot", the relevant code would be something like:

```
new File('file path') << new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).meta.count
```

More details:

- [Groovy: JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)

Comment: I think it should be prev.getResponseDataAsString() instead of prev.getResponseData() as your code @Dmitri T

Comment: I think it should remain as is, [**prev** stands for a SampleResult](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) or derivative class instance and it has [getResponseData()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getResponseData--) function which returns a byte array representation of the response body.  Casting it to a String will result into double work on both JMeter and JsonPath sides, performance-wise it's better to work with the byte array

Comment: Good to know about it, that's my lesson learnt in my next Test Plan. Thank you @Dmitri T